# Stored procedure not picking up parameter from web page

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm struggling to get a query to run and display results via a web form. Its using a parameter to pass the value into a stored procedure, but although the @status value is set, it doesn't appear to be picked up by the sp and so returns no results. My Vb is pretty limited and I suspect that's where the problem is.

Heres the SQL:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[get_status_times]

@status nvarchar
as

select project_code, activity_code, project_date, project_time from 
timesheet where status = @status
```

and the vb

```
Sub detailsClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles listweekstatus.ItemCommand
    Dim wccolumn As TableCell = e.Item.Cells(0)
    '  Dim timeColumn As TableCell = e.Item.Cells(1)
    Dim statusColumn As TableCell = e.Item.Cells(2)
    ' Dim buttonColumn As TableCell = e.Item.Cells(3)


    Dim wccoltext As DateTime = wccolumn.Text
    ' Dim timeColText As String = timeColumn.Text
    Dim statusColText As String = statusColumn.Text
    ' Dim buttonColText As String = buttonColumn.Text

    Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("chronosdb").ConnectionString)

    Const strSQL As String = "get_status_times"
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection)


    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    myCommand.Parameters("@status").Value = statusColText
    myCommand.Parameters("@status").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

    'Set the datagrid's datasource to the datareader and databind
    myConnection.Open()
    weekdetails.DataSource = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    weekdetails.DataBind()


End Sub
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your parameter declaration in your proc:

```
@status nvarchar(200) --For example
```

The existing declaration will be trimming your input to the first char:

For example the following code:

```
create proc paramtest (@param nvarchar)
as
begin
select @param
end
go

exec paramtest 'foobar'
```

Just selects `f`

Comment: +1 [When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx)

Comment: What a star you are Jon. That sorted it out.  All the time I've been thinking the vb was wrong and its the SP. Many thanks for this.

Comment: @DaveHenderson: nps - its often the little simple stuff that it takes someone else's eyes to notice. Glad to help.

Comment: @DaveHenderson: Don't forget to mark this as your answer by clicking the tick mark above. Taa